# 360 degree robot touch sensor with full coverage

Tags: sensor

Years ago, I read an article that described a unique homebrew 360 degree coverage robot bump sensor.    It did not rely on switches; instead, the device was a rubber/foam tubing with an electrical piece wedged in between.    When pressure was applied at any point, it would make contact.   By measuring the current (?), you could determine where on the 360 degrees of the bumper the contact occurred.     But, I don't remember the details.   For example, did the measurement rely on resistance?  Or something else?   I have not been able to find any references to such a sensor.

Any thoughts?